# Facebook friends likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to know, in my app, if 10 friends of the user liked my facebook page.
I can't either access to the friends via

```
 FB.api('/me/friends?access_token=<?php $this->access_token; ?>',
 function(result){ 
     console.log(result); 
 })
```

How I can obtain the likes of all my friends in a particular page?

Answer (score 0):

To find the list of friends who like a page, you can only get this via FQL. You need to make sure your access token has the `friends_likes` permission.

You can modify your code to get the list of a user's friends who like your page like this:

```
FB.api('/fql?q=<?php urlencode(
    "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id={$your_page_id} ".
       "AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
     );?>&access_token=<?php echo $this->access_token; ?>',
```

Comment: I've used the solution in my answer, but when I will refactor the code, your is best! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To the end, my final code is:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token=<?php echo $this->access_token; ?>', 
        function(response){ 
            i=0;
            for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
                searchForLikes(response.data[i].id);
            }
            if(friends_like>=<?php echo FRIENDS_LIKE; ?> && step<3){
                stepReach(3, friendsNum, 80);
                $.post("/default/index/next-step", { userId: '<?php echo $this->user->getId(); ?>' });
            }
        });
```

I so use the searchForLikes function to make my code :3